# Rails API Omniauth (Facebook) Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, facebook-login, omniauth-facebook

I have a Rails API which is stateless, with Devise gem for authentication and using Devise generated `auth_token` to authorise each request. Now I want to add login via Facebook with following flow:

1. User authorise the Facebook app to get required data.
2. Redirect to certain page according to Facebook settings (`/auth/facebook/callbacks`).
3. Get or create user (if not registered yet).
4. Redirect to previous page (before we click *login with facebook*) **with `auth_token`.**

The problem is in step 4, how do I get the `auth_token` via json after redirect. Anyway, the auth_token is generated each time user created or signed in successfully (via email & password).

Any best example for this?

Thanks

Comment: You can also refer to https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Facebook Javascript SDK (using `FB.login()`). Instead of Devise Facebook Omniauth. Then I send the response to the back end API.

Comment: I am struggling with this as well. I figure from your answer that the Facebook Login flow is handled by the Javascript frontend, which makes sense. In my case my API serves a mobile app so the app will handle the Facebook login flow. However, once the user logs in via the frontend, how do you send the Fb data (user_id and access token) back to the API in order to properly generate the auth_token?

Comment: @Augusto I also have the same issue. Could you redirect me to the best approach? I will have to build a mobile app for Android, IOS and I am trying to understand how to do the Rails Backend API for the Facebook-Omniauth authenticated users. Thanks Fabrizio

Comment: Hello Fabrizio. I ended using a customised version of devise_token_auth gem. Are you using a gem to authenticate your API calls?